# PHP mysql calculating between 2 columns

Tags: php, mysql

I want to calculate how much percentage is positive and negative for voting.  For instance, I have like 5 positive and 5 negative votes it should make it 50%, right?

How can i do that in a mysql/php query?

The columns are like this:

> no yes yes no no no no yes yes yes

Comment: instead of having an unlimited number of columns yes, no why not just record all votes in one column

Comment: i'm sorry i said columns .. i mean the values are like that in the column vote_column

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, 
       100 * sum(vote_column = 'yes') / count(vote_column) as percentage
from your_table
group by id
```

Comment: That's not quite how you calculate percentages.  Shouldn't be more like `100 * sum(vote_column = 'yes') / count(vote_column)`?

Comment: i don't know if this works ? how can i define it to echo it ? i now have this 100 * sum(stem = 'yes') / sum(stem = 'no') AS percentage and then i echo $percent['percentage'];

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat ye i'm still busy but this works for now: select stem, 
    sum(stem = 'ja') / count(stem = 'nee') * 100 AS percentage
from stemmen

WHERE id = '$_GET[id]'